# Xcode project can't find Bolts/BFTask.h file after Cocoapods update

Tags: ios, cocoapods, bolts-framework

I was running my Parse project with no problem. However, after I updated to the latest version of cocoapods and running pod install, Xcode is throwing an error "Bolts/BFTask.h file not found". I've looked tried to look up other cocoapods header related issues and none of the solutions work or pertain to this specific problem. If anyone can provide some guide, I would appreciate it.

Steps:

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods 
 pod install
```

Error message came after running above commands in the terminal, now Xcode is unable to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to "Clean Build Folder" if anybody has experienced this problem. Just press "option" key on Product -> Clean.